# gdalwmscache folder on Windows

Tags: qgis, gdal

Could somebody explain what the gdalwmscache folder does?

Is it save to delete the gdalwmscache folder on Windows? Is my file still able to be opened? I can't test this so it would be nice of someone could clarify a few things.

A customer recently migrated from Windows fileshares to Sharepoint online and has a lot of these folders with more than 2000 items per folder in it what is slowing down Onedrive / Sharepoint.

Comment: if you found this answer helpful, you could upvote it as answering your question

Answer (score 3):

Documentation related to WMS cache from https://gdal.org/drivers/raster/wms.html

```
<Cache> Enable local disk cache. Allows for offline operation. (optional, defaults to no cache)

<Path>./gdalwmscache</Path> Location where to store cache files. It is safe to use same cache path for different data sources. (optional, defaults to ./gdalwmscache if GDAL_DEFAULT_WMS_CACHE_PATH configuration option is not specified)

<Depth>2</Depth> Number of directory layers. 2 will result in files being written as cache_path/A/B/ABCDEF… (optional, defaults to 2)

<Extension>.jpg</Extension> Append to cache files. (optional, defaults to none)

<Type>file</Type> Cache type. Now supported only ‘file’ type. In ‘file’ cache type files are stored in file system folders.

<Expires>604800</Expires> Time in seconds cached files will stay valid. If cached file expires it is deleted when maximum size of cache is reached. Also expired file can be overwritten by the new one from web. Default value is 7 days (604800s).

<MaxSize>67108864</MaxSize> The cache maximum size in bytes. If cache reached maximum size, expired cached files will be deleted. Default value is 64 Mb (67108864 bytes).

<Unique>True</Unique> If set to true the path will appended with md5 hash of ServerURL. Default value is true.

</Cache
```

You can safely delete the cache.